# Query 2 tables with left join that id dont exist in 3rd table

Tags: sql

I got

```
table1    table2       table3

id         id           id
name       table1id     customerid
           table3id
```

How can i fetch the table1.name joining table2 where customerid = someid and table3id not exist in table2

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you want to do.

Comment: Sebastian, I rejected your edit because that would make the LEFT JOINs INNER JOINs so if that is what you want there is something else going on.  As gordon mentioned maybe you could add some sample data and an expected result so we can see more clearly what you are wanting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SELECT
       t1.id
       t1.name
    FROM
       Table1 t1
       LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
       on t1.id = t2.table1id
       LEFT JOIN Table3 t3
       on t2.table3id = t3.id
       AND t3.customerid = 93
    WHERE
       t3.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thats working good and from t1 i got customerid too i will add it with t1.customerid = id and its working.Thank you

Comment: ????? I am a little lost....wait did you put the customerid in the where clause?  If you do that it will treat the LEFT JOIN as an INNER JOIN so it needs to go into the on condition, I have updated the answer for you.

Comment: You are retrieving rows in Table1 and Table2 that do not map to any row in Table3. This means that searching for a specific row in Table3 as part of that query is unlikely to mean what you might think it means.

Comment: @RobertColumbia, From the question it sounds like what he wants. My guess is he wants to find all rows in table1 that do not relate to cusotmerid 93....... Unless he wants to the reverse which is to find all records in table3 with customerid 93 that don't have a corresponding record in table1 in that case simply reverse the order of the joins....

Comment: @Matt I was trying to get all table1 records For the specific t3.customerid that doesnt have t3.id in table2. And for what i wanted to see in my results adding t3.customerid = 93 in WHERE clause works

Comment: sebastian, If you feel you have want you want then go for it.  But your narrative of what you are asking for is actually impossible because table2 is the only relation point between t1 and t3 so if t2 doesn't have a relation to t3 then t3 cannot be related to t1.  What you would end up with is a list of every t1 that does not relate to t3.customerid = 93.

Comment: Yes but in t1 i got ownerid = customerid so i think that will work fine

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table1.name
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.table1id
WHERE table2.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table3)
```

Comment: table2.id is not in table3 rather table3's id is at table2.table3id.  Also EXISTS should perform better than IN.  Plus you should look into when NULL is part of the result set in IN it will return all records because NULL is unknown.